# Why we cannot initialize the member variable of a class in C++

Tags: c++, member-initialization

It's giving error:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class stud
{
    int a = 0; // error??

public:
    void display();
};

int main()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Use constructor to initialize that variable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What compiler are you using? In older versions of C++ (namely, C++03), that code won’t compile, but newer versions of C++ (C++11 and onward) should compile that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*(The cause)*

Non-static data member with a default member initializer is supported since C++11.

--

*(The fix)*

These days, many compilers support C++11.

For Visual Studio IDE users (like myself): On project properties: C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard: Set to C++11 or above. In Visual Studio 2017 C++11 is supported at baseline.

For other than Visual Studio IDE users, search the topic: "How to enable C++11" for your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this from C++11 [onwards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

> Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration, which is used if the member is omitted in the member initializer list.

```
class S
{
    int n = 7;
    std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    S() // copy-initializes n, list-initializes s
    { }
};
```